# How to get Big O time complexity of code?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I have a good understanding of Big O notation, but I am very confused about this question:

> Given a Sorted List with N elements, and that the key being searched is repeated R times in
>   the list, what is the complexity of my_search() in terms of O notation?

```
def my_search( data, key ):
 found = False
 low = 0
 count = 0
 high=len(data)-1
 while ( not found and low<=high):
     guess = (high+low)//2
     print('guess: ', guess)
     if ( key == data[guess] ):
         found = True
         count = 1
         k = guess - 1
         while k>=0 and data [k] == key:
             count += 1
             k -= 1
         k = guess + 1
         while k < len(data) and data [k] == key:
             count += 1
             k += 1
     else:
         if (key < data[guess]):
             high=guess-1
         else:
             low = guess+1
 print('count:', count)
 return count
```

The passed arguments for this function is a list and a key, the function calculates how many times the key appears in the list, for example `my_search([1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,7], 1)`. The answer key says that the time complexity for this code is  [image: this] , how did they come up with this answer?

Comment: It seems this question better fits at https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Taegyung Thanks for the suggestion, I did not know about CS stack exchange, I'll post there next time, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

searching in an ordered list is O(log(N)) ([binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)). once you have found the element you are looking for you need to check (at least) R elements against the item you have searched for. so in total O(log(N)) + R.

Comment: I see, I was confused because I thought log base 2 (N) was different from log(N), but I guess not. Thank you!

Comment: well technically it should be log2(N) but as log2(N)=log(N)/log(2) they only differ by a constant factor which is kind of irrelevant when talking about complexity. i probably should have written log2 anyway...